# What exactly does the word "or" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Let's consider the following question.

Enumerate all the persons in the following list who are male **or** American.

A) Male, French

B) Female, American

C) Male, German

D) Male, American

E) Female, Italian

Which is the correct answer: "A, B, C, D" or "A, B, C"?

Comment: Please explain the reason for the close vote.
Otherwise I can't improve the question.

Comment: What is the language issue? I assume you understand what "or" means so it's not clear why you're uncertain of the correct answer.

Comment: I meant it as a [leading question](http://www.yourdictionary.com/leading-question). You need to add more detail to your question, otherwise folks are going to tell you "look it up in a dictionary". I think your question would be better if you incorporated some of the thoughts you've expressed in your comments about whether "or" in this context means exclusively one or the other or if it means that "Male,American" meets the criteria. Right now your question reads as if you are trying to get us to do your homework (which I know you're not) and it could be better.

Comment: @ColleenV "*I meant it as a leading question.*"

Why do you think it is a leading question?

"*You need to add more detail to your question, otherwise folks are going to tell you "look it up in a dictionary".*"

Could you show me a dictionary which answers my question?

Comment: If your question is "what is the meaning of or?", any dictionary can answer that. That isn't your exact question. My suggestion is to add more detail explaining why your question can't be answered with a dictionary. Explain in your question why you are uncertain whether the answer is ABCD or ABC. Or don't if you don't want to - these are just my suggestions. The post http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/465#465 has some good advice on how to write excellent questions and probably explains it better than I'm doing right now :)

Comment: I'm afraid I do not get the subtlety of the question from your post either. Could you please explain a bit why you think OR here might be equivalent to the logical OR (exclusive)?

Comment: @ColleenV "*If your question is "what is the meaning of or?", any dictionary can answer that.*" My question is clearly stated: Which is the correct answer: "A, B, C, D" or "A, B, C"? If you think any dictionary can answer this, please show a dictionary that actually does it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just say that OR  is inclusive (that is, it means one, the other, or BOTH) when it makes sense that both could be the case. If the options are "mutually exclusive" (i.e. one being true prevents the other from being true) then the OR is assumed to be exclusive (either...or).

Since in your example it is clearly possible to be both male and American, I think that option should be included. In ordinary English.

So yes, D) is part of the correct answer.

(If the exam was on Logic, it should have explicitly stated which kind of OR was meant.)

Comment: "*i.e. one being true prevents the other from being true*"

In this case, there's no problem on the meaning of the word "or".
The point of my question is whether the case D) should be included or not in the answer.

Comment: sorry, I thought that was clear when I said "inclusive", because Paul Senzee already mentioned. Fixing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or in English is inclusive, that is, it would be A, B, C, D.

In programming one distinguishes between Inclusive (English-like) Or and Exclusive Or.  Exclusive Or (xor) yields A, B, C in this case.

Exclusive Or in English is *either .. or*.

Comment: "*Or in English is inclusive, that is, it would be A, B, C, D.*"

Could you show some evidences for this claim of yours?

Comment: http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/or

Comment: It seems to me that the article just states the statement without showing an evidence.

Comment: It's the dictionary.  What more evidence do you require?

Comment: The article has the following example sentence.
"*It's raining! Come inside or you'll catch a cold!*"
This "or" seems to be exclusive.

Comment: In that context, I agree, it's exclusive. I'd consider it a shortened form of **Either come inside or you'll catch cold.** That's one thing about English - all the exceptions.